# Where Gita is mentioned in Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, bhagavad-gita

We all know that Gita is a part of Mahabharata. But it is very difficult for me to find it in Mahabharata. Please help me.

Note:- Clearly mention the parva and chapter

Comment: there is a school of thought that believes the Gita is a latter day interpolation into the Mahabharata

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It starts with Bhagawad Gita Parva of Bhishma Parva in Mahabharata.

The link to that Parva (Sanskrit and Transliteration version) has been provided below;

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs06023.htm

---

The link to that Parva (Translation) has been provided below;

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06013.htm